# Smallest positive integer that has $x_{1},x_{2}, \dots, x_{t}$ with $x_1^3 + x_2^3 + \dots + x_t^3 = 2002^{2002}?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the smallest positive integer $t$ such that there exist integers $x_{1},x_{2}, \dots, x_{t}$ with $x_1^3 + x_2^3 + \dots + x_t^3 = 2002^{2002}?$

I don't really get what the question means by "such that there exist integers $x_{1},x_{2}, \dots, x_{t}$ " and I don't know how to start.

Comment: Suppose $t = 1$. Does there exist an integer $x_1$ such that $x_1^3 = 2002^{2002}$? In fact there does not, because $2002^{2002}$ is not a perfect cube. Therefore, $t \geq 2$. You can imagine the same question for $t = 2$, namely, "do there exist integer solutions to $x_1^3 + x_2^3 = 2002^{2002}$?" Your question asks what the *minimum* number of such terms you need on the left hand side for there to exist integer solutions.

Comment: For sum of two cubes, see [this](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL6/Broughan/broughan25.pdf). [Sums of three cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_three_cubes) is a hard problem.

Comment: I would have try a modulus approach, and $t$ is lower than 9 using Waring theorem.

Comment: The question is asking: Suppose we want to express $2002^{2002}$ as a sum of cubes. How many terms do we need?

Comment: @EDX: Whether intentional or not, the question doesn't restrict the $x_i$ to being _positive_ integers. 132479: Was this intentional?

Comment: @TonyK Yes you're right I don't know if it is intentional

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evaluating $2002^{2002}$ mod $9$, we get
\begin{align*}
2002^{2002}
\!&\equiv 4^{2002}\;(\text{mod}\;9)\\[4pt]
\!&\equiv 4{\,\cdot\,}4^{2001}\;(\text{mod}\;9)\\[4pt]
\!&\equiv 4{\,\cdot\,}(4^3)^{667}\;(\text{mod}\;9)\\[4pt]
\!&\equiv 4{\,\cdot\,}1^{667}\;(\text{mod}\;9)\\[4pt]
\!&\equiv 4\;(\text{mod}\;9)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Noting that $\{x^3\;\text{mod}\;9\mid 0\le x \le 8\}=\{0,1,8\}$, it's easily verified that
$$x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3\equiv 4\;(\text{mod}\;9)$$
has no integer solutions.

It follows that the equation
$$x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3=2002^{2002}$$
has no integer solutions.

Hence the least qualifying value of $t$ must be greater than $3$.

But identically we have
\begin{align*}
2002^{2002}
&=
2002^{2001}{\,\cdot\,}\,2002\\[4pt]
&=
2002^{2001}{\,\cdot\,}(1000+1000+1+1)\\[4pt]
&=
\left(2002^{667}\right)^3{\,\cdot\,}(10^3+10^3+1^3+1^3)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which is a sum of $4$ cubes.

Therefore $t=4$ is the least qualifying value of $t$.

Comment: Why did you choose $9$ as modulus? Did you try all the smaller ones?

Comment: @lhf: Yes. It was easy to see that $t=4$ works. For the problem to be sufficiently elementary, I felt that for $t=3$, a congruence failure mod $n$ for some small $n$ was likely.

Comment: For anyone wondering: A good thing to note is that for any positive integer $n$, $x^n \equiv -1, 0, \text { or } 1 (\text{mod } 9)$. That's why mod 9 works well here.